# Overlay multiple images on one video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to encode multiple images over the same video at different times in a single pass.

I have a fair grasp of doing this with a single image, such as

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i picture1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,1,5)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy result.mp4
```

but how would I go about adding a picture2.png, picture3.png, and so on, with different between() parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Add all the images you want to overlay to a video file as input `-i`

Here -

1. X,Y are the top left coordinates where the image should be put, with respect to video
2. Between(t,a,b) means you want to display that image from a (in seconds) till b (in seconds)
3. gt(t,c) means that display that image from c till the end of video

> ffmpeg -i video -i image1.png -i image2 -i image3  -filter_complex
> "[0][1]overlay=x=X:y=Y:enable='between(t,23,27)'[v1];
> [v1][2]overlay=x=X:y=Y:enable='between(t,44,61)'[v2];
> [v2][3]overlay=x=X:y=Y:enable='gt(t,112)'[v3]"
> -map "[v3]" -map 0:a  out.mp4